# Positive and negative impact of predictors on responses in data mining models

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest, predictor

My question is an extension to the question asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158434/can-i-interpret-the-impact-of-variables-like-positive-or-negative-on-the-model-b). How does one identify the parity of predictor/feature/variable impact on response/outcome in a data mining model. Is there a standard procedure to find the 'direction' of impact after one does feature selection and derives variable importance using methods such as regularized random forest or lasso/elasticnet?

I know this question may sound quite naive, but I really wanted to know and I have searched SO and other materials but couldn't find a convincing answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I don't thing there is a standard approach.
- ["Boosted Regression Trees for ecological modeling"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dismo/vignettes/brt.pdf) is a commonly cited reference that briefly discusses some of these issues in the context of boosting. Partial dependence plots are available in many packages.
- `Rminer` is a package the uses sensitivity analysis to extract information from models. Underused and has the benefit that you can use almost any model with this methodology.
- `Soren Welling` is an active member on this site - has authored the
  [`forestFloor][2]` package and goes into some depth into getting
  information from blackbox models in the following stackexchange answer:
  [Getting Information out of Blackbox Models - RandomForest / XGBoost](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172761/getting-information-out-of-blackbox-models-randomforest-xgboost/172839#172839)
- I haven't looked at the [ggforest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggRandomForests/) package, but this also offers to open the black box.

Comment: Thx for the referral :) -  pkg is called *forestFloor*

Comment: aaaah. Sorry about that.